# Probabilities involving "at least one" success

Tags: probability

Isabella built a time travel machine, but she can't control the destination of her trip. Each time she uses the machine she has a $.25$ probability of traveling to a time before she was born. During the first year of testing, Isabella uses her machine $5$ times.

Assuming that each trip is equally likely to travel before Isabella was born, what is the probability that at least one trip will travel before Isabella was born?

Round your answer to the nearest hundredth.

I get the answer $1-.75^4$

However, the correct answer is $1-.75^5$. How is this the answer? If finding the complement wouldn't we account for one of the times being before she is born?

Comment: What does the $P$ mean?  The answer is $1-.75^5$

Comment: Yes I should have removed it. It means "the probability of". Why not $1-.75^4$ though? How do you account for the probability of her being born?

Comment: Where did you get the $4$ from? It’s $5$ trips...

Comment: @b00nheT I thought since one of the trips is before being born, that you should subtract one from the total amount of trips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not need to account for probability that she was born, it is known to us.

You want at least $1$ case, so why not calculate none, or $0$ case, and subtract it from total number of cases?

Or simply, $$P(at least\hspace{0.2cm} 1)=1 - P(none)  $$
$P(none)$ means calculate probability that she always goes in **future**.
$P(future)=0.75$ for $1$ trip.
So, for $5$ trips, it will be $0.75^5$.
Subtract this from $1$:

You get $$1-0.75^5$$

---

If this confuses you, calculate discretely for cases: exactly **once**, exactly **twice**,**thrice**, **four** times and **five** times.
$$P(exactly \hspace{0.2cm} once)=(0.25)\cdot (0.75)^4$$
$$P(exactly \hspace{0.2cm} twice)=(0.25)^2\cdot (0.75)^3$$
$$P(exactly \hspace{0.2cm} thrice)=(0.25)^3\cdot (0.75)^2$$
$$P(exactly \hspace{0.2cm} 4 \hspace{0.2cm} times)=(0.25)^4\cdot (0.75)^1$$
$$P(exactly \hspace{0.2cm} 5 \hspace{0.2cm} times)=(0.25)^5\cdot (0.75)^0$$
Just add all probabilities: $$(0.25)^1\cdot (0.75)^4+(0.25)^2\cdot (0.75)^3+(0.25)^3\cdot (0.75)^2+(0.25)^4\cdot (0.75)^1+(0.25)^5\cdot (0.75)^0$$
Verify if you get same result!

Comment: @Jinzu have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: You are missing some binomial coefficients!

Comment: @b00nheT which one?  $1$ over 0.25 in exactly once case?